# Agora - Is there anyway I can know how many users currently joined in channel?

Tags: agora.io

I would like to know the total number of users currently in the same channel. This is a crucial information I believe.

`Scenario`
Caller initiates call by joining the channel -> A push goes to receiver -> Caller decides to leave call/channel before receiver joins. When the receiver reacts to push and joins the channel, sees no one in that channel. If I had a way to tell the receiver that there's no one in that channel at the moment then the receiver could be notified with dialog or some sort.

**Note:** without using the RTM library. Can this be done with RTC only?

Comment: did you get a solution for this using RTC sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RESTful API to get a list of users in the channel: https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/dashboard_restful_communication?platform=All%20Platforms#gets-the-user-list-in-a-channel-get

You can also implement the Agora RTM SDK together with Agora RTC SDK and implement the logic for users to join the same channel as using Agora RTC SDK. And call getMembers method to get a list of users in the RTM channel.

Here is the API document for getMembers method: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtm_1_1_rtm_channel.html#a567aca5f866cf71c3b679ae09b4bf626

Here is a quick start guide for the RTM SDK: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android

Comment: These option are all from agora RTM sdk. We use RTC sdk. I wish there was a better way I could retrieve this information from rtc sdk. Adding another(rtm) sdk just to get total members in channel isn't really a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

While using agora rtm for messaging,We can use getMembers() functionality which is provided by agora to get the active people in a channel in agora.I am defining it using javascript below for reference.

In javascript,Define a function GetMembers()-->

```
name='The channel Name of your channel';


function GetMembers(name)
{
       rtm.channels[name].channel.getMembers().then((memberNames)=>{
              /* memberNames contains an array of the names of the members*/
         })
  }
```

Call the GetMembers() function wherever it is required to get the names of the active members.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of joined members using getMembers method of agora rtm. Remember it also gives your own id if you are logged in. This method return array.

```
 GetChannelMembersList()
   {
     channel.getMembers().then(async (memberNames)=>{
       console.log(memberNames, 'memberNames');
      for (let index = 0; index < memberNames.length; index++) {
        const user = await rtm.client.getUserAttributes(memberNames[index].toString()); 
console.log(user, 'user'); // To find more details of joined user
     
      } 
            })
     }
```